# Deserialize GET response

Tags: c#, json

How do I deserialize this text. I tried with JSON but I get "Invalid JSON primitive" error.

```
{
"meta": {
  "limit": 20,
  "next": null,
  "offset": 0,
  "previous": null,
  "total_count": 1
},
"objects": [
  {
     "blocked": false,
     "groups": [],
     "id": "1111",
     "name": "John Doe",
     "number": "+15555555555",
     "resource_uri": "/api/v1/contacts/1111/"
  }
 ]
}
```

This is the code I used:

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dictionary = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(buffer.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to Fix. Deserialize to `<Dictionary<string, object>` instead of `<Dictionary<string, string>`

```
var dictionary = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(buffer.ToString());
```

Full test code

```
string json = @"{
    ""meta"": {
        ""limit"": 20,
        ""next"": null,
        ""offset"": 0,
        ""previous"": null,
        ""total_count"": 1
    },
    ""objects"": [
        {
            ""blocked"": false,
            ""groups"": [],
            ""id"": ""1111"",
            ""name"": ""John Doe"",
            ""number"": ""+15555555555"",
            ""resource_uri"": ""/api/v1/contacts/1111/""
        }
        ]
    }";

var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dictionary = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```